# Website slightly changing its UI when accessing from selenium - Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, web, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having a problem when accessing websites using selenium and chromedriver (even though I implemented successfully all the steps I found to avoid selenium detection): when I access it from my normal browser, the UI is perfect, as expected, but when I open it from Selenium one button disappears.

To avoid detection:

```
 options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
 options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

The UserAgent that I'm currently using is the same as my browser (I copied and pasted it)

Does anyone have any suggestion for me?

Comment: So what is your question? changing UI or avoiding detection?

Comment: I need to access the UI that is "hidden", I guess by better avoiding detection (?)